# How to remove the double quotes and skip last 3 lines in bcp loading into SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am loading data into SQL Server using bcp command line utility.
The problem is data is coming is like below. Every field in double quotes and I have to skip last three rows because it has some trailers. How can i solve this?
Thanks in Advance. I appreciate if you could help in this.

```
bcp database.schema.tablename in Filename.text -T -c -t"|" -r"0x0a" -F 3 -m 2

UHDR 20211110
"DATE","CUSIP","ISIN","SEDOL","TICKER","DESCRIPTION","QUANTITY","RATE","COMMENT","MARKET","FEE"
11/10/2021|""|"CA45826T3010"|"BMVXZT5"|"ITR"|"INTEGRA RESOURCES CORP REGISTERED SHS"|"28712"|"0.0000"|"HTB"|"CA"|"11.5000"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to:

- unconditionally remove all `"` chars.
- unconditionally skip the last 3 lines:

```
(Get-Content -ReadCount 0 Filename.text) -replace '"' |
  Select-Object -SkipLast 3 |
    Set-Content Filename_CleanedUp.text
```

<sup>Note: `-ReadCount 0` is a performance optimization that makes [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) read all lines into a *single array* instead of *streaming* the lines one by one.</sup>

Then pass `Filename_CleanedUp.text` to your `bcp` command.